# Matlab Faster Image Import

Tags: image, matlab

Hi I am trying to import jpg files (on average around 500 images) from a specific folder. I tried to do it with the following code

First method:

```
function Seq = ImageImport(imgPath, imgType,Amount)
    images  = dir([imgPath imgType]);
    N = length(images);

    % check images
    if( ~exist(imgPath, 'dir') || N<1 )
        disp('Directory not found or no matching images found.');
    end

    % preallocate cell
    Seq{N,1} = [];
    
    if Amount == "all"
        for i = 1:N
            Seq{i} = imread([imgPath images(i).name]);
        end
    elseif Amount == "first"
        Seq{1} = rgb2gray(imread([imgPath images(1).name]));
    end
end
```

Second Method:

```
function Seq = ImageImport(imgPath, imgType,Amount)
    images  = dir([imgPath imgType]);
    N = length(images);
    
    % check images
    if( ~exist(imgPath, 'dir') || N<1 )
        disp('Directory not found or no matching images found.');
    end
    
    % preallocate cell
    Seq{N,1} = [];
    
    % preallocated filepath
    filepath{N,1} = [];
    for i = 1:N
       filepath{i} = sprintf('%s%s',imgPath,images(i).name);
    end
    
    if Amount == "all"
        for i = 1:N
            Seq{i} = imread(filepath{i});
        end
    elseif Amount == "first"
        Seq{1} = imread(filepath{1});
    end
end
```

the second method was faster than a little bit faster but still takes too long to import the image files, is there a way to be able to speed up the import of the files

Comment: Are all images the same size (in pixel dimensions) and file type or are they different.

Comment: The first thing to try is specifying the file type as the optional second argument to `imread`.

Comment: You should also use `strcmp` or a `switch`-`case` statement instead of `==` to compare char arrays or strings.

Comment: You should start by using the MATLAB profiler https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html to work out where the time is being spent. If all the time is inside `imread`, then there might be a lot you can do. Running in parallel using `parfor` might be an option.

Comment: @horchler one of the joys of `string` arrays in MATLAB is the ability to compare using `==` - no need for `strcmp` - is there a specific reason you suggested that?

Comment: You've not really done much in terms of pre-allocating memory by creating a _cell array_ to hold all of the outputs. It would probably be much quicker to pre-allocate an `NxAxB` matrix if all of your images are of size `AxB`, and then assign each image into a "slice" of that matrix